# PowerApps portal site has all web files missing

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

I am working on a PowerApps portal (power pages) and have been using it for almost 8 months, we have developed many custom forms and pages in this portal. All of a sudden today morning, all the web files are failing to load.
I checked Portal Management >> Active Web files and cannot see any of the web files (image files, css files, JS files) associated with my portal site, in the Active Web files view. It is very strange as till yesterday it was all there. Even when I check the solution in VS Code, the web files are present though, they have somehow disappeared from the portal and I am unable to get them back.

I am trying to upload from the solution back to the portal using the command --> pac paportal upload --path
But, still no success in getting the web files become available in the portal again.

Any clue or help on this issue will be very much appreciated.